# Upper and Lower sums - Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $P_1 \subset P_2$ then it follows that:

$$L(P_1) \leq L(P_2) \ \ \  \text{ and } \ \ \ U(P_1) \geq U(P_2)$$

Can someone explain why this is true intuitively or graphicly?

Comment: Can you clarify your notation?

Comment: i do apologize I'm kind of new to this I will update my question so that it's more clear

Comment: Here's a starting point: can you see why this is true when $P_1 = \{a,b\}$ (that is, we didn't partition the interval at all!) and $P_2 = \{a,x_1,b\}$ (so a single interior partition point splits the interval into two subintervals)?

Comment: Yes! thank you seeing it that way makes it a lot easier.... I was a bit fuzzy about the subset meaning but now I see that they basically mean is the one set has more sub intervals (or points) then the other....when i think of it that way this seems pretty straight forward :)